# Constructor call error message

Tags: java, constructor

Any ideas why I may be seeing the following message for this class?

```
package org.swx.nursing.tools.sqlfinder.gui;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public final class GuiTemplateImpl  extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public void createAndShowGUI(GuiTemplateCriteria guiCriteria) {
        super(new BorderLayout());


    }
}
```

Message

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor   GuiTemplateImpl.java    /sqlfinder/src/main/java/org/swx/nursing/tools/sqlfinder/gui    line 29 Java Problem
```

I am not sure why this will not work. The error goes away when i remove the super(), so this seems to be causing some issues.

Comment: You cannot call `super()` nor `super(args)` in a non-constructor method.

Comment: @Baby that's not a direct duplicate of this problem.

Comment: Thanks Luiggi for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super` let you call base constructor or base method. It is not clear what exactly you trying to achieve:

- if you trying to create constructor than its name must match type name. It is the only place where you can call base constructor with `super(...)`, and as error message says it must be first statement:

Code:

```
public GuiTemplateImpl(GuiTemplateCriteria guiCriteria) {
    super(new BorderLayout());
}
```

- if you are trying to create method that will call base implementation:

Code (probably not what you looking for based on arguments mismatch):

```
public GuiTemplateImpl(GuiTemplateCriteria guiCriteria) {
    super.GuiTemplateImpl(new BorderLayout());
}
```

Comment: thanks! i used the method by oversight. been a long day. my bad

Answer (score 2):

`super()` must exist in *constructor* not a method. like:

```
public final class GuiTemplateImpl  extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    public GuiTemplateImpl(GuiTemplateCriteria guiCriteria) {
        super(new BorderLayout());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. that was the issue, i mistakenly used this by oversight :/ ...been a long day i guess